# Accessing Object within Form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

i try to access the first element of a array within my @user object and get the first object
out of that array. I just bring it not to work. Here is the code:

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if params[:redirect_to] -%>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'redirect_to', params[:redirect_to] %>
      <% end -%>
#Thats not working
       Last booking:   <%= f.text_field Booking.where("user_id="+ @user.id+").order('start_date DESC').first%>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all You are trying to push a whole Booking object into the field, which seems to be wrong, probably You want some particular value like booking_date or something like this.

```
Booking.where(user_id: @user.id).order(:start_date).last.booking_date
```

Secondly You have a syntax error there and text_field method expects name of the user model field. If You defined has_many :bookings then You should use fields_for. Remember if You use form_for form builder You must reference model fields, if You need something custom use `text_field_tag` instead.

```
text_field_tag :booking, Booking.where(user_id: @user.id).order(:start_date).last.booking_date
```